How to call query-replace-regexp in elisp with capture groups and functions in replacement string
I want to write a few functions that call query-replace-regexp with regex and replacement strings that are too complicated to remember and to hard to figure them out again every time I need them.
For example I want to replace binary literals in C with their hex value.
(so replacing 0b0011 with 0x03 for example)
The query regexp when calling query-replace-regexp interactively is
0b\([01]+\) and the replacement string is \,(format "0x%02X" (string-to-number \\1 2))
Now I want a function that does exactly that, replacing the binary with hex using query-replace-regexp.
But I can not get the replacement string right. I seems like it doesn't know that it should call a function when there is \,(
This is what I tried
(defun pascal/query-reg-rep-C-binary-to-hex-constant ()
  "Replace binary constants in C switch cases with their hex equivalent"
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "0b\\([01]+\\)" "\,(format \"0x%02X\" (string-to-number \\1 2))"))

This replaces 0b0011 with ,(format "0x%02X" (string-to-number 0011 2)). So its not calling the function.
(defun pascal/query-reg-rep-C-binary-to-hex-constant ()
  "Replace binary constants in C switch cases with their hex equivalent"
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "0b\\([01]+\\)" (format "0x%02X" (string-to-number "\\1" 2))))

This does not use the capture group somehow, it replaces 0b0011 with 0x00.

Instead of manually creating such a function, I find it easier to record and name a keyboard macro performing the search and replace, using kmacro-name-last-macro and insert-kbd-macro.

@rsp Thanks, this is a good idea. Sadly query-replace-regexp does not work in a kmacro for some reason. I got (defalias 'C-replace-binary-constant-with-hex-constant    (kmacro "M-x q u e r y - r e p l a c e - r e g e x p <return> 0 <return> 1 <return>")) and all it does is moving the point to the next 0 in the buffer. But it fills the history of query-replace-regex, so I can call this and then call M-x query-replace-regex again and just press return and I'm there.

Always check the documentation. C-h f will show you the documentation for any named function, and if you read the documentation for query-replace-regexp you will find the following line:
In interactive calls, the replacement text can contain \,
followed by a Lisp expression.

But you’re not calling it interactively, so it doesn’t check for a \,.
The documentation also recommends reading the documentation of perform-replace. If you do that you will find that it starts like this:
Don't use this in your own program unless you want to query and set the mark
just as query-replace does.  Instead, write a simple loop like this:

  (while (re-search-forward "foo[ \\t]+bar" nil t)
    (replace-match "foobar" nil nil))

Combining that with your regular expression and desired replacement, you would write something like this:
(defun pascal/query-reg-rep-C-binary-to-hex-constant ()
  "Replace binary constants in C switch cases with their hex equivalent"
  (interactive)
  (while (re-search-forward "0b\\([01]+\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match (format "0x%02X" (string-to-number (match-string 1) 2)))))

Note in particular that the replacement is simply ordinary lisp code; it is not embedded into a string. You also must call match-string directly.

Thanks, but I came to this solution as well, but it replaces all the occurrences in the buffer beginning from point to the end of the buffer without querying. I fumbled in a yes-or-no-p inside a (let ...) but while this works in the scratch buffer, it does not in a C buffer for some reason. The match-string 0 becomes #endif and the match-string 1 in nil.
